# When shall the Django Self Referential Foreign Key be used and WHY?

Tags: django

I am new to Django and this question may seem to be dumb. Why shall the Django self referential Foreign Key relationship be used? and When?

For example,

```
class Person(models.Model):
      follower = models.ForeignKey('Person')
```

Why shall the self referential be used here?

Comment: Did you just not answer your own question ?

Comment: It might be better to use 'follower' instead of 'friend' as the example, because the foreign key is not symmetric. If Alice's friend is Bob, that doesn't mean that Bob's friend is Alice.  You can however follow the relationships backwards - `alice.person_set.all()` will return all the people who have `friend=alice`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you gave allows you to represent that one person (e.g. Alice) has a single friend (e.g. Bob). You might prefer a many to many field if you want to allow people to have multiple friends.

For recursive relationships, it's fine to use either 'self'

```
  friend = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

or name the model explicitly

```
  friend = models.ForeignKey('Person')
```

It doesn't matter which you use. Personally, I would prefer 'self', because it makes it obvious that the foreign key is recursive.

Comment: For recursive relationship, it can be interpreted as "Alice has a friend Bob who has a friend Carl who has a friend Daniel, etc..."?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't need to be an endless chain though. You could have Alice has a friend Bob who has a friend Carl who has a friend Alice.